# VS Code - Python 3.8.3 Interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code (1.45.1) and Python 3.8.3 (64 bit).

Installed both fresh today, and the strangest thing is that VS Code keeps telling me "Select Python interpreter". I do, using either that prompt or command palette, and I have to manually browse to the path where I keep (Hesitant to muck with Environment Variables, not on a personal machine). When I do that, the popup disappears, but the error persists. As others have suggested I looked at editing the vs settings json and added

```
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python38\\python.exe",
```

Testing on a basic script (.py) I was able to right click-run in Python Terminal (or Shift Enter). When that terminal opens, I ran:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

I get back:
3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]

So the python extension cant find an interpreter, but I can clearly interact with it. Any thoughts/help is appreciated!

Comment: Hey at the bottom of vsc there should be a tab showing which version of python it's pointing to,  click it and select your python3 destination folder

Answer (score 0):

Here are the pictures just in case you can't find it:
With a python script opened in your VSC, there should be a tab at the bottom showing which python folder it's using:
[image]

Hit that and select where your python is installed:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the images, unfortunately mine does not show verion. It currently just says Python (before said magic python, since disabled in case it was that).

Comment: If no interpreter is selected it would show a yellow warning sign at the bottom panel. When you click on the "Python" it should say configure Python language based settings, click that and double-check is shows the python.pythonPath line at the end. If it does try opening the command palette and type "python: Select Interpreter". It should then show the available interpreters

Comment: I get a popup that says "No Python interpreter is selected. You need to select a Python interpreter to enable features such as InteliSense, linting, and debugging.
Source: Python (Extension).

When I do click the select (in the popup, as part of the error, or in the command palette)  it shows 3.5.2 (32 bit) but no option to do the 3.8.3 I installed today. It goes on to let me "Enter a path" and brings up a file browser. I use it, select the .exe Python (64 bit) and it doesn't resolve the error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the python path in the settings. Selecting the interpreter does not solve the issue. After following the suggestions in this [comment](https://github.com/pilat/vscode-importmagic/issues/19#issuecomment-880282632) it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the interpreter by editing the settings.json as you mentioned:
I had to change my 3.10 version back to my 3.9 version to work with TF. So I simply changed the old file path ("C:\SomePathTo\Python3\python.exe"):

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\SomePathTo\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe"
}
```

Only then I was able to see the Python version when I clicked on the kernel interpreter.